# Missing .env files when I use React native Config for android

Tags: reactjs, config, native

I have configured my project like this document says. I am running the app I am getting this

JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> Configure project :app
>   Reading env from: .env
>
> ---

*** Missing .env file ****

---

https://medium.com/differential/managing-configuration-in-react-native-cd2dfb5e6f7b

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: If using `create-react-native-app` and then `yarn eject`. You should able to run `react-native run-android` without any changes. Might need to run `gradlew clean` from command line under **android** folder, if it can't create gradle build.

Comment: yes i did that does not help. I did eject earlier.

Comment: None of the ejected native project work or just a particular one?

Comment: Just this one I found the issue fixed according to this thread 
 https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/95  but I am using 0.11.5 which is supposed to have the fix

Comment: eh...The dependency has to match up perfectly. It better to run `npm update -g create-react-native-app` every time before creating a new project. Don't try manually update the gradle packages. They are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply remove filename**
For example Config.env ( Here is a problem ),

**It should be like**

.enn & .env.qa